# Activity orientation in ActivityGroup

Tags: android, layout, tabs, screen-orientation, activitygroup

I have problem with recreating activity in `ActivityGroup` when orientation of screen is changed. This is the structure of app:

I use `TabActivity` with `TabHost`. From each tab own `ActivityGroup` is started and works like stack for next activities. Problem occures when I change orientation in some activity in `ActivityGroup`. System ignores orientation change and activity isn't recreate. (layout for landscape isn't loaded)

I tried handle orientation change by `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` but I can't call `recreate()` method in any activity in `ActivityGroup` because it causes error: 
*recreate() method can be call only on top-level.*

Has anyone some advice, please??

Comment: ActivityGroup is deprecated. I recommend you to use Fragment